# Which parts of classical enactments division do the laws of Gortyna contain?

Tags: criminal-law, rape, sanctions

According to the classical scheme, modern enactments include 3 parts: hypothesis, disposition, and sanction. Is this scheme applicable to archaic laws of 7-5 BCe?

For example: "if you rape a free woman, you have to pay 10 staters". Is the part: "if you rape a free woman" a hypothesis or a disposition? To me it looks like the hypothesis because it contains conditions.

And is the next one: "you have to pay 10 staters" a disposition or a sanction? It looks to me as the disposition part, because there's no information about what will happen if you don't pay.

Comment: You’ll have to explain what “classical scheme” is.

Comment: I meant the structure of enactments (hypothesis-disposition-sanction), google said that it's called classical scheme

Answer (score 2):

> Is this scheme applicable to archaic laws of 7-5 BCe?

Not in the example you provide, although legal systems that predate the Gortyn code contain portions which present the structure hypothesis-disposition-sanction.

Disposition is [defined](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/disposition) as "*the final determination of the court in a criminal charge*". Thus, the law "*if you rape a free woman, you have to pay 10 staters*" only contains a hypothesis and a sanction. The disposition is implicit, i.e., implied by whether or not the accused person is sanctioned.

By contrast, some portions of ancient laws do contain a[n explicit] disposition. As an example, consider rules 11 and 12 of the [Code of Hammurabi](https://avalon.law.yale.edu/ancient/hamframe.asp). Both rules include the proposition (or disposition) "*he is an evil-doer*" right in between a hypothesis and the corresponding sanction.